# Directory, listing, linking and displaying files in php

Tags: php, directory

I'm trying to build a directory browser, where I can list the folders. When clicking on a folder name, files are shown below like an accordion or dropdown.

Then when a file name is clicked I need to show the file within the same window without refreshing.

All the files have .pdf extensions.

I have the setup of the list on the left and the file display on the right, but not sure how to achieve this.

Below is what I have so far, basically just listing the directory folders and their file and linking them.

```
<?php
    function listFolderFiles($dir){
        $ffs = scandir($dir);
        echo '<ol>';
        foreach($ffs as $ff){
            if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
                echo '<li class="title">';
                if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)){
                    echo $ff;
                    listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
                }else{
                    echo '<a href="'.$dir.'/'.$ff.'">'.$ff.'</a>';
                }
                echo '</li>';
            }
        }
        echo '</ol>';
    }
    
    listFolderFiles('folder-name');
?>
```

Comment: @BharatBhatiya I'm thinking I need to use jquery. The code above is functional and does what the other question was asking for.

Comment: Better use directoryiterator

Comment: A search by google will tell you how to use php directoryiterator. Hint: look at php.net

Comment: @bub yeah, coz of course I didn't do that. . .